# How do I round out this curve

Tags: bezier-curves, smooth

[image]Sorry this is a really basic question, but I had this curve which I have a shape following. I would like to round out the corners so it isn't so sharp. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in edit mode, press A, Curve -> set spline type -> bezier

[image]

Then press V > Automatic or Aligned (if it isn't rounded already)

Comment: Then press V > Automatic or Aligned?

Comment: good idea ;) in my test it worked without it ;)

Comment: oh ok in my test it kept orthogonal points (V > Vector)